# Problem with setting initial voltages in LT Spice

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, high-voltage

I was trying to set an initial voltage for a capacitor I was modeling in LT Spice, and I tried using the command .ic V(Vc)=20000 (Vc is the node directly after the capacitor, with ground on the other side), but the result it gave me was like this:
[image]
Circuit schematic:
[image]
There is a AC square wave source, but this is the part being measured.
I figured that it would be more of a consistent curve, but it looks like it just immediately jumps and then discharges as I think it should.  Is there another way to give a capacitor an initial voltage?

Comment: Can you share your schematic? Without it, there's no way for us to know what's going on.

Comment: Try to set -20000

Comment: Any difference if you add a say 100 Mohm resistor to ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, there is an initial spike of whatever you imposed it to be, but then the voltage discharges quickly through `D21`-`D23`-`D20`-...-`D1` to ground. The circuit is behaving normally, I'd say. BTW, you named the same node twice: `Vout` and `Vc`. In this case, LTspice will consider the last placed name.

Else, for any circuit involving initial conditions, you can try adding `.tran 10m uic` to complement the `.ic` card. Or delete the `.ic` card and set `ic=...` next to `C1`'s value, like this: `2n ic=20k` (btw, those `F` do nothing, unless they are the first letter, when it means `femto` -- avoid units). This should work without `uic`, too.

Comment: Oh, so the voltage multiplier I have effectively is a short circuit?  Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this circuit is all the wires are superconducting and the caps (most likely) do not have any parasistics attached. If you have a cap with no ESR or ESL and a wire with no resistance, the current in circuits like this can go to infinity and the solver will have a difficult time finding initial conditions.

Make sure you have appropriate values of ESR and ESL, you can do this by looking up a capacitor of comparable size datasheet, or by estimation.